# Cannot debug tests using Resharper - Cannot Launch Debugger

Tags: c#, tdd, resharper

I'm not able to debug my tests using Resharper-Debug option in my project. I have seen this issue raised by lots of people, but has't come across a solid suggestion which solves my issue.
The strange thing is that, if I create a sample project and write a simple unit test, I'm able to debug it without any issues.However when I try to do this in my current project, it simply throws a dialog box saying "Cannot Launch Debugger".I have checked this with my peers, and they does't face this issue :(

Also I don't have any issues while running the test.

It's an XP machine and following is the version of resharper:

> JetBrains ReSharper 5.1 C# Edition
>   Build 5.1.1753.4 on 2010-10-15T15:51:30
>
> Licensed to: XXXXXXX
>   Plugins: none.
>   Visual Studio 9.0.21022.8.
>
> Copyright © 2003–2011 JetBrains s.r.o.. All rights reserved.

Thanks,
-M

Comment: What unit-testing framework are you using?

Comment: So what's different between your environment and your peers'? Do you have any error logs under local app data, JetBrains?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I occasionally encounter a test that can't be launched with the Resharper debug icon (due to mock objects or 32 vs 64 bit dlls). A solution that works for me is to add an explicit call to launch the debugger in the test

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

Then just run the test as normal. When code execution hits that line you get a security popup (pick yes)

[image]

then a visual studio choice popup (pick your currently running visual studio).

[image]

You'll be dropped into your code in debug mode at the location where you added the Debugger.Launch() line.

Comment: solved my problem of my debugger sort of only half running :/ very odd. thanks

Answer (score 21):

Possibly of use to someone stumbling here, specifically, I encountered the error:

```
---------------------------
ReSharper – Unit Testing
---------------------------
Cannot launch debugger.

Error code: 89710016

Error message: 0
```

when using R# 8.2 on VS 2013 Pro when attempting to debug NUnit tests.

After [finding this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329556), the issue resolved by changing the NUnit class library project to x86 (`Properties -> Build -> Platform Target : x86`)

Comment: Helped me. VS 2015. R# 2016.3

Comment: Worked for me as well VS 2015 14.0.25431.1, R# 10.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the build properties of the Project to be x86 (which can impact other team members if working on a team), you can tell Resharper to run the unit tests in a 32 bit process.

> Resharper -> Options -> Tools -> Unit Testing ->General -> Default Platform Architecture

Set this to "Force tests to run in 32-bit process"

Comment: Worked for me as well VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

Changing to x86 did not work for me.

What worked was using Managed Compatibility Code in VS (2017) : Tools-> Options -> Debugging -> General -> checking Use Managed Compatibility Mode.

VS Pro 2017 15.7.6, R#2017.3.2